# Is it possible to work with javascript:void(0) in android app

Tags: javascript, android, android-fragments

I am new to android. We have a web application where on menu click we are hiding some div and showing other. Now I have to load the page in web view which I have done well with URL. But there is a condition with a java script function based on which I should load page. And it is the problem. The function is as follows ::

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getmenudata('Home')">
```

or

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getmenudata('About')">
```

Now my question is, is it possible to call such type of java script function from android ?!! If possible please can some body help me to how to write my URL using this type of function ?

Comment: Why shouldn't this work in a web view?

Comment: it works well in web view. But I need to load some fragment using url instead of link clicked in my app.

Comment: *"load some fragment using url"* - I have no idea what you're trying to say. Do you want to "launch" a fragment from a webview? Take a look at intents.

Comment: no I already done it. What I want is to make the URL using `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="getmenudata('Home')">`

Comment: Did you enable Javascript in your WebView? webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

I solve it.

just add this line onPageFinish() >>>

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                webview.loadUrl("javascript:getmenudata('Home')");
          }
```

// here getmenudata is my java script function and Home is my param value.

And override this method as follows >>>

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
```